# How to code load modules on all nodes in Distributed Erlang?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I am learning Erlang/OTP, and in Chapter 14 it says:

> "you can load Module to all nodes use shell command : `command nl(Mod)`".

I want to know, how to do this? I can't find the shell command : `command nl(Mod)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tried to type `help().` in shell? This function is defined in [c module](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/c.erl#L259) in stdlib. But shell will understand `nl(Mod).`

To perform test, start at least two erlang vms and connect it:

```
erl -pa your_module_path -name first@127.0.0.1
erl -name second@127.0.0.1
```

in first shell connect to second node by:

```
net_kernel:connect('second@127.0.0.1').
```

should respond with `true`.

In `your_module_path` create some simple module like:

```
-module(nl_test).
-export([test/0]).
test() -> 1.
```

and compile it by `c(nl_test).` Now you can run `nl_test:test()` from first shell but the second one can't load it. To broadcast it and force load, just run from first `nl(nl_test).` Now try from second shell `nl_test:test()`.

Let's say you modified `test() -> 1.` to `test() -> 2.` and all you need to do is to just run `c(nl_test), nl(nl_test).` or shorter `nc(nl_test)` which means the same.

`nl_test:test().` on all your connected nodes should return `2`.

This may look very easy but in complicated production systems, proper hot-loading is quite advanced problem.